# How to upload image using ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'm search in the internet for a solution. I find some of them but they didn't work for me. Basically I have an input form on a laravel project where I want to upload an image with ajax request.

On the Get request instead of sending the image is sending the following parameter value [object%20FormData]

I know that I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what it is. Can anyone help me? Here is my Html code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{{ URL::route('upload') }}}" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
    <button type="button" id="upload_image_btn" class="btn btn-default">Upload!</button>
</form>
```

And here is my ajax code

```
var image = $('#image')[0].files[0];
formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( 'image', image );
formdata.append( 'action', 'image' );

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '{{{ URL::route('upload') }}}',
    data: formdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        $.each(errors, function (key, data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                $(".upload_error").text(data);
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me to find what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

SOLUTION: as the comment says, I changed the GET request of ajax to POST and it work. Thank you for your help

Comment: Send it as a Post request and try

Comment: You cannot send files through get method, you have to use post

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the image data from the form input element for security reasons.  You can get the file name, but not the actual path on the uploader's computer.  You'll probably need to fake the ajax by posting the form to a hidden iframe.